# Bash, how to modify all the rows of a file after a placeholder?

Tags: bash, shell, token, bash-completion

I have a table file that I would like to modify this way: w**hen I found a particular placeholder, I want the next lines to be modified according to it, before meeting the new placeholder, after which the next lines will be modified in another way, etc.**

This is my sample table:

```
chr2.0  46580   46730   A_206699
chr2    46580   46730   A_206949
chr2    47020   47170   A_206699
chr2    47020   47170   A_206949
chr2.1  1680380 1680530 A_206997
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206956
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206963
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206966
chr2.2  1697600 1697750 A_206980
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206981
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206982
chr2    1697600 1697750 A_206983
 ..................................
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206982
chr2    1748280 1748430 A_206983
chr2    1748280 1748430 A_206984
chr2    1748280 1748430 A_206986
chr2    1748280 1748430 A_206987
```

And I would like to have a bash script that takes this input and produces the following output:

```
chr2.0  46580   46730   A_206699
chr2.0  46580   46730   A_206949
chr2.0  47020   47170   A_206699
chr2.0  47020   47170   A_206949
chr2.1  1680380 1680530 A_206997
chr2.1  1697600 1697750 A_206956
chr2.1  1697600 1697750 A_206963
chr2.1  1697600 1697750 A_206966
chr2.2  1697600 1697750 A_206980
chr2.2  1697600 1697750 A_206981
chr2.2  1697600 1697750 A_206982
chr2.2  1697600 1697750 A_206983
 ...................................
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206982
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206983
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206984
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206986
chr2.9  1748280 1748430 A_206987
```

How could I do?
Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit**: the placeholder is the dot in the first element of the row.

Comment: How do you identify the placeholders? Periods in the first field?

Comment: Yes, that's my placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to do what you want (though it won't keep the column spacing unfortunately).

```
awk '$1 ~ /\./ {f=$1} {$1=f; print}' input
```

Pipe that to `column -t` to get (slightly different) columned output.

Answer (score 1):

If you're into regular expressions, either awk or sed can do it (awk would be a bit more wordy, sed streamlined and impenetrable ;)

Since you're not asking about them, though, I'm guessing they may be foreign to you, and you can certainly do it in bash:

```
key=''
cat $input_file | while read first rest
do
    [[ "$first" != chr?.? ]] || key="$first"
    printf '%s  %s\n' "$key" "$rest"
done > $output_file
```

You *can* redirect the input *and* output at the end of the `while` loop, but it's a little easier to read this way.  You may also want to get a little bit more elaborate with the formatting in `printf`, but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Do you have a `sed` solution? I would be curious to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then echo 'usage: require one argument.' >&2; exit 1; fi;
file="$1";

widths=(8 8 8 8);

suffix='';
while read -r; do

    ## parse
    line="$REPLY";
    i=0;
    fields=();
    for width in "${widths[@]}"; do
        field="${line:$i:$width}"; ## extract
        field="${field%"${field##*[![:space:]]}"}"; ## rtrim
        fields+=("$field");
        let i+="$width";
    done;

    ## save new suffix, or apply last known suffix
    if [[ "${fields[0]}" =~ (\.[0-9])$ ]]; then
        suffix="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
    else
        fields[0]="${fields[0]}$suffix";
    fi;

    ## print
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#widths[@]}; ++i)); do
        printf '%-*s' "${widths[$i]}" "${fields[$i]}";
    done;
    printf '\n';

done <"$file";

exit 0;
```

Your data is a fixed-width table, so correct parsing of it requires knowing the widths of the fields. I've hard-coded them in the script, but if you don't want to do this, you can pass them through another channel, perhaps via a header line in the file, or in a separate file. Alternatively, if the file is known to be delimited (e.g. by whitespace), the script can be modified to parse on a delimiter. However, keeping track of the field widths allows preserving the alignment, which your question seems to imply you want to do.

Comment: At a cost of array storage for all the fields of all the lines you could learn the field widths during read and use that on output too.

Comment: That requires assuming delimiters for parsing. Granted, the data the OP posted does look whitespace-delimited in addition to being fixed-width, but I wanted to make my solution independent of any delimiter assumption. This makes the code more flexible, in that individual fields can contain whitespace.